# Usage of values stored in $_GET / $_SESSION in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, session

i'm pretty new to Javascript and PHP so please bear with me if i'm asking some really dumbed down questions.

Ok, say i need to use values stored in a PHP $_GET or $_SESSION, is it advisable to just do something like

`var something = PHP echo $_SESSION or $_GET`

Comment: it is not advisable. it's just the only possible way. I strongly suggest to learn javascript first or it would be pain to learn 2 languages at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the data safe for JavaScript to parse. `var something = <?php echo $SESSION['foo']; ?>` would work if it is a number. If it was a string you need to add quotes. If the string contains special characters then they need to be escaped, etc.

Running the data through [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) is a good way to make it JavaScript safe.

Since $_GET is user entered data, you can't know that it is a number without checking, so if you don't make things safe then you have a huge XSS hole. Even if you do, then what you do with the data in JavaScript afterward could sill expose you to XSS.

Comment: Thanks for the info on handling $_GET data. However, i still do not understand what does json_encode do that makes data javascript safe.

Comment: @Felix: Sadly, I only know it's a data structure with name: value pairs in it but absolutely no knowledge on what it is commonly used for

Comment: Why don't you mention SESSION for the XSS too?

Comment: @luhiz — it is a data format that is a subset of JavaScript, so you can dump it directly into JS.

Comment: @Col - $_SESSION contains whatever you put into it, not what the user puts into it. (It is implied that if you earlier take from GET and put into SESSION then you have the same problems)

Answer (score 0):

Putting this as an answer for the code formatting, but...

@luhiz: think of what happens you're inserting data into a javascript block that contains javascript "meta characters". Let's say you're passing a person's full name as a query parameter, like this:

```
http://example.com/index.php?name=John+O'toole
```

In PHP, you'll have:

```
$_GET['name'] = "John O'toole";
```

and when you place it into the javascript block, you'll get:

```
var name = John O'toole;
```

Now you've got a few problems:

1. You've inserted raw user-hackable data into your page
2. A javascript syntax error as your string is not enclosed in quotes
3. Another syntax error as the name contains a single quote, which begins a string which is then not terminated with another quote.

Discussion:

1. This is a classic XSS (cross-site-scripting) attack. You're placing user-provided data into an html page without any safety. The simplest attack example is to use `http://example.com/index.php?name=alert("you've been hacked!");`. Try it and see what happens.

2&3: By using json_encode, PHP automatically converts whatever you're encoding into syntactically safe Javascript. This doesn't mean it's "safe" code - it can still contain malicious data. But it will not cause a syntax error when the page is loaded by the client browser. So by doing:

```
 var name = <?php echo json_encode($_GET['name']);
```

you'll get something like:

```
 var name = "John O'toole";
```

which the javascript interpreter will accept without any complaints.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! Now i get a better understanding of this whole issue